# Xcode 7 finding the cause of SIGABRT

Tags: swift2, sigabrt, ios9, xcode7-beta5

I am using Xcode 7 beta 5 and creating a multiview application. One view has a button that brings you to a second view, but when this button is pressed it crashes with Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT.

I have checked all the connections of things inside the target view, and everything appears to be ok (I also went through and redid them to be sure). I have tried adding an exception breakpoints which stopped for something, but I am unsure how to find the faulty line.

I have also tried adding breakpoints manually, and have found the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var wakeTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func snoozeButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    snooze()
}
```

If I put the breakpoint on the first line there (after all the other outlets), it catches, but when I put it on the function line it throws the SIGABRT. If I remove these two lines completely, the SIGABRT still occurs.

The console contains the following:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key whiteSwipe.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x182a2da94 0x197387f80 0x182a2d754 0x1838a3694 0x18829b378 0x1883dd874 0x1829575ac 0x1883dc25c 0x188602fd8 0x1886077c4 0x188607a38 0x188607c94 0x187f755bc 0x187f75538 0x187f5dfa0 0x187f74e50 0x187f74a80 0x187f6dcf0 0x187f3eea4 0x187f3d520 0x1829e50dc 0x1829e4b70 0x1829e2870 0x1829118a0 0x18d96c088 0x187fa60d4 0x1000b4be0 0x197bd68b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you said you redid your connections, `Sigabrt` is what I recall to be a exception thrown by faulty connections. In particular, your error message is the one that comes out when you change a connection's signature after you've connected it.

For instance, I just got a very similar message after deleting 1 character off an `@IBOutlet` declaration:

```
FeedViewCollectionCell 0x7feab0c583b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.
```

I suggest you reconnect your outlets again. Make sure you don't have 2 of the same connections on an item, and make sure you don't change the signature after setting the outlet.

Comment: Just tried this again (deleted the code, right clicked the objects and hit the x), and the same thing is still happening. Are there other possible causes/solutions? Is there a way I can identify the faulty line?

Comment: Since the error message mentioned `whiteSwipe`, check wherever you declared `whiteSwipe`.